# Why does a test scope dependency add compile scope dependencies?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

Why does adding the following result in compile scope dependencies?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>myproject.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>api</artifactId>
  <classifier>tests</classifier>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

[INFO] +- myproject.core:api:jar:tests:5.0.5-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-x-discovery:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.7.1:compile
```

I'd expect copy-dependencies with an exclusion on test scope to not only skip the top level but remove it and its transitives from the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between test dependencies and test-jar dependencies.

For test dependencies, the scope of transitive dependencies are correctly set to test (see [this table](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) in the Maven reference).

For test-jar dependencies (what you have here), the behaviour is different. I couldn't find anything in the Maven docs explaining why it is different (maybe someone else with better insight can explain why). However, I found a bug report ([MNG-1378](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-1378)) about this, which remains unresolved after more than 10 years, so I would not get your hopes up.

Comment: Ok, so I'm not crazy, maven is simply a little broken.  So, my work around would be to push tests or test utility code into their own modules.  I don't love it but it's a viable option.